# Joining on column IDs that are very similar but not exact (and editing them to be exact)

Tags: sql

I have two tables and the values are almost the same.

In one of them I have an ID of "001" and the other I have an ID of "RPM: 001" and this holds true for all the values in the two tables.

What are some ways I can join these tables?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can use any condition in the `on` clause.  So, in standard SQL, you can do:

```
from t1 join
     t2
     on t2.id = 'RPM: ' || t1.id
```

`||` is the ANSI standard operator for concatenation.  Not all databases support these, but all have some method for string concatenation.

EDIT:

In T-SQL, you would use `+` for string concatenation:

```
     on t2.id = 'RPM: ' + t1.id
```

This assumes that `t1.id` is a string.  Otherwise, you need to convert it:

```
     on t2.id = 'RPM: ' + cast(t1.id as varchar(255))
```